# is there a way to stop reading a line after a specific character (*)

Tags: java, character

I'm programming in Java and am struggling to find a way to stop reading a line after coming across a specific character which is the `*` sign.

Here is a snippet of the code and what I have come up with.

```
String reader = buffRead.readLine();
int NUMBER_OF_LINES_IN_FILE = Integer.parseInt(reader);
buffRead.readLine();

for (int counter = 0; counter < NUMBER_OF_LINES_IN_FILE - 2; counter++) {
    String line = buffRead.readLine();
    StringTokenizer Tok = new StringTokenizer(line);
    while (Tok.hasMoreElements())
        System.out.println(Tok.nextElement());
    if (ch == '*') {
        break;
    }

    //Declare a variable (line) and set its value to the line read
    //from the buffRead stream
    print.println(line);
    //Use the println method to write the line to the PrintWriter Buffer
}
```

Comment: you could also use String's contains() method : eg `if (line.contains("*")) {..}`

Comment: This isn't the correct way to use StringTokenizer. Also, what is "ch"? You could use line.contains("*") as @funkyjelly suggests, it is the best and the most correct way to do this.

Comment: Also, use upper case names only for constants and don't use the capital letter for variable names. These are some conventions that helps you and us to read the code better :)

Comment: Kazi is new to Stack Overflow, please remember to be kind :)

Comment: well thanks for some tips, i have come further into my solution with the line.contains("*") method. Now i am trying to add the  first element in the first line with the next 4 lines.

Comment: Kazi, please describe the current output.

Comment: Kazi, if your question is answered, please add an answer and credit @funkyjelly, unless they want to write an answer themselves.

Comment: @funkjelly for the answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below is one way of reading a file line by line. It will print out all lines and will stop when a * is encountered (It will also print out the line containing the * up until the * position). Also as mentioned you should use contains() method of String class :

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("/path/to/file"))) {
      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          if (line.contains("*")) {
              System.out.println(line.substring(0,line.indexOf("*")));
              break;
          }
          System.out.println(line);
      }
} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to read the lines up to the character '\*', not skipping the lines with a '\*'

Comment: @Michele updated answer to also print out the part of line containing the `*` , up until the `*` char